# add padding to TextField cursor / center the TextField cursor in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have a `TextField` and when i change `cursor height` it comes down . i want it come center or add padding under it.**

Cursor should be vertically `center` of `TextField` is that possible ?

[image]

**and this is my code.**

```
TextField(
        cursorHeight: 30,
        cursorColor: Colors.yellow,
        cursorWidth: 2,
        cursorRadius: Radius.circular(500),
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
        obscureText: isPasswordTextField ? showPassword : false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.yellow),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            suffixIcon: isPasswordTextField
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        showPassword = !showPassword;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.remove_red_eye,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(28, 28, 28, 1),
            labelText: labelText,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              fontSize: 22,
              fontFamily: 'Exo',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
            hoverColor: Color.fromRGBO(54, 54, 54, 1),
            hintText: placeholder,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Colors.white,
            )
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. As you can see in the your textfiled there is no height specified.

```
TextField(
          cursorHeight: 30,
          cursorColor: Colors.yellow,
          cursorWidth: 2,
          cursorRadius:const Radius.circular(500),
          style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14,  
                   height: 1.5 //Add this
           ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.add your extra code also I tried to design

```
  TextField(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.remove_red_eye,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
              // floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(28, 28, 28, 1),
              labelText: 'labelText',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontFamily: 'Exo',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              hoverColor: Color.fromRGBO(54, 54, 54, 1),
              hintText: 'placeholder',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]